# Find files in directory listed in csv file and copy to new folder

Tags: batch-file, csv, command

I have a directory full of scanned documents, grouped into different folders and subfolders based on year, month and date.  Each scanned document has a unique barcode number assigned to its filename.

What I'm trying to do is write a command that will use a list of these barcodes in a csv file and search the directory and subdirectories for the relevant files, then copy them into a new folder I have on my local drive.

This is what I have so far..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set id=0
if not exist AllFilesFolder mkdir AllFilesFolder

set "theDir=Z:\INVS"

for /f "delims=" %%i in (theFile.csv) do (
    copy %theDir%\%%i.* "C:\Data")
```

Really hope someone could help me out on this one.  I've probably wasted more time trying to get it to work than trying to find the files the old-fashioned way, but if I could get it working it'd save time in the future.

Many thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I hope I interpreted you question right.
I assume, `theFile.csv`contains only the barcodes, without the complete path:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (theFile.csv) do (
  for /f %%j in ('dir /s /b %theDir%\%%i.*') do (
    copy "%%j" "C:\Data"  
  )
)
```

Comment: AWESOME! You're a star Stephan, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Can I be a bit cheeky and ask for a slight amendment?  Would it be possible to alter each filename as it's copied over?  For example to add 001- at the start of each filename.

Comment: `001` to each of the filenames, or do you want a "counter": `001` to the first file, `002? to the second one and so on?

Comment: A counter if possible.  Just so we can rescan the images in the order they were entered on the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: the `usebackq` allows `thefile.csv` to be specified by path as well, and to contain spaces or & in path or filename.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("theFile.csv") do (
   for /r "%theDir%" %%b in ("%%a.*") do copy "%%b" "C:\Data"  
)
```